# firebase authentication sms payment

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We are currently using authentication Phone Auth in our firebase project.

I am using Spark, a free plan, and I understand that I can send to 10 SMS per day.

As a result of the SMS test, it was confirmed that 11 SMS messages were being sent, and 11 messages are displayed in the usage monitoring. So, will I be charged?

Also, is there a way to check the number of SMS usage per day?

Or can SMS send 50 per day, and is code authentication a limit of 10 per day?

It was a free version, so I couldn't charge it and I was hoping there would be an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your project is on the free plan, you will not be charged for any operations on the project.

There is no public API to check the number of messages that have been sent.

Comment: Even if the number of SMS exceeds 10, the process continues. Does it matter?